# pandas: how to get the sum of rows by grouping inside a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am new to Data Science and I am currently using the Pandas library on the Jupyter notebook. Sorry for my poor English.

```
A,1,5,9
B,2,6,3
A,3,7,2
B,4,8,1
```

How to group the above CSV values also adding the contents after creating the DataFrame?
I want the output something like this.

```
    A   B
0   4   6
1   12  14
2   11  4
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
df
   0  1  2  3
0  A  1  5  9
1  B  2  6  3
2  A  3  7  2
3  B  4  8  1

df.pivot_table(columns=0,aggfunc='sum').rename_axis(columns=None)
    A   B
1   4   6
2  12  14
3  11   4
```

Answer (score 0):

This is groupby + sum with transpose:

```
print(df.groupby(0).sum().T.rename_axis(columns=None))
```

---

```
    A   B
1   4   6
2  12  14
3  11   4
```

Note: replace 0 in `df.groupby(0)` with the actual column name of the first column